# App never be suspended after enter background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

My app uses `bluetooth low energy wireless technology`, and needs to run in background to perform certain bluetooth-related tasks, so declare that it supports a core bluetooth background execution mode in the Info.plist file. App would start to read RSSI per second after a connection is established from a ble device, the delegate method "peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:error:" of `CBPeripheralDelegate` will be invoked . According to apple docs, the `bluetooth-central Background` Execution Mode chapter describes:
In addition, the system
wakes up your app when any of the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` or
`CBPeripheralDelegate` delegate methods are invoked, allowing your app to handle
important central role events, such as when a connection is established or torn
down, when a peripheral sends updated characteristic values, and when a central
manager’s state changes. 
Because my app always read rssi both foreground and background per second. Whether my app never be suspends? Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking?  Are you asking if your app will never be suspended?  Or are you complaining that it never is suspended?

Comment: I think what he meant to ask is why "peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:error:" never called when app is background? I have the same issue and still Googling right now...

Answer (score 0):

Because you have specified in your `.plist` that your application requires background processing, your app will always wake up when ever the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` or `CBPeripheralDelegate` delegate methods are invoked. Otherwise your app will be sleeping away like a baby in a cradle under a peaceful and blissful night.